# The Secretary General of the UN is dead. Who acts in his place?

Tags: earth, law, modern-age, united-nations

António Guterres, the Secretary General of the UN, and many other UN employees were killed when Jormungandr, the Snakebot of Doom steamrolled New York city in January 2017.

Now, in early February 2017, aliens have come to negotiate with the people of Earth, and the UN is [the most logical body to deal with them](https://www.thespacereview.com/article/2770/1) on behalf of the whole world.  However, the world has been thrown into disarray by Jormungandr's attacks, the UN offices in New York have been destroyed and many UN personnel are dead, and no official successor to the position of the Secretary General has been appointed.

So, my question is:

Does the UN have a chain of succession, and how can I work out who would be acting Secretary General?  I'm not after the name of the real-life people who might succeed the UN Secretary General, I'm looking for the positions whose incumbents (whoever they are) would be selected as - or who could function as - the replacement Secretary General in an emergency, pending proper selection of a new Secretary General.  In the event that there is no such person in the UN, or there is no clear chain of succession, is there any other person or group who could act in the UN Secretary General's stead?

**Edit:**

The answer to this question is *not* 'trivially googled'... enter the wrong search terms, and you get nothing useful.  Additionally, the UN website has many broken links.  Finally, while this may seem to be a trivial piece of information for which a worldbuilder could search, the answer may be necessary for a person's worldbuilding effort.  I certainly found it so for mine, unless I wanted António Guterres to have a miraculous escape when so many non-famous New Yorkers didn't.

To address another issue mentioned in comments, it doesn't matter that the UN doesn't have any power delegated to it by any nation, since the Secretary General is a [required point of contact](https://www.seti.org/protocols-eti-signal-detection) in the event of first contact with aliens.

Comment: The Secretary General of the U.N.O. (and the U.N.O. in general) does not have any power to negotiate anything on behalf of Romania, or of any other country. There is no particular need to have a chain of succession for the leadership U.N.O., any more than there is a need to have a formal chain of succession for the leadership of the World Association of Girl Guides and Girl Scouts. The question shows a fundamental misunderstanding of what the U.N.O. is. In particular, no country on this Earth has delegated even the tiniest shred of power to the U.N.O.

Comment: @AlexP -- And the UN has precisely that! Most organisations do, in fact, have some kind of plan in place to determine who takes over in a crisis situation. Even if it is WAGGGS!

Comment: @elemtilas: A plan for who takes over is not a plan of succession. It is just a plan to have somebody *acting* in the leadership role(s). For example, in the U.S.A. if the President falls under a bus, the President of Vice becomes President; that is a rule of succession: no new elections are needed. If the S.G. of the U.N.O. falls under the same bus, the Deputy S.G. is abilitated to *act* in place of the S.G., but a new S.G. still needs to be proposed and approved using the normal procedure.

Comment: More importantly the question is asking who else can execute Article 99 and doesn't jaywalk ;D

Comment: Bad overlords? Wow! I have no idea what Arthur Clarke would think about this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no world-building component, this is research into actual facts. The question, "Who succeeds the SecGen of the UN" doesn't become worldbuilding because "one was killed by a snakebot" is typed into the description. The premise doesn't even require the SecGen to be dead.

Comment: @VogonPoet in what way are actual facts not relevant to the process of worldbuilding?

Comment: @MontyWild "Attempt to do your own research. If a quick google search will answer your question it may not be worth posting a question on the site. Generally, querents are expected to demonstrate what has been tried and why it was not sufficient or did not work. " Questions about Earth's history are explicitly off-topic in the help center, and "UN succession" has an answer in history. Questions about modern Earth can be on-topic, if worded correctly. your "fiction" contributes nothing at all to the "problem" (which is merely a research problem)

Comment: @VogonPoet Have you tried browsing the UN website?  It has  lot of broken links...

Comment: I timed this at 12 seconds. [In a Crisis, Does the UN Have a Leadership Succession Plan?](https://www.passblue.com/2020/03/23/in-a-crisis-does-the-un-have-a-leadership-succession-plan/). It took 2 minutes of another participant's time to create your hyperlink. Basic courtesy, please at least try.

Comment: "Article 97 of the UN Charter spells out the process for appointing a secretary-general: The Security Council recommends a candidate to the General Assembly, which votes to confirm or not. At the time of Hammarskjold’s death, the Charter did not delineate a line of succession, leaving a void in the UN’s top leadership for a few months." It wasn’t until 1997 that a formal line of succession was established. SecGen Kofi Annan ...included the position of deputy secretary-general. should the secretary-general become unavailable, ...an under secretary-general is designated as officer in charge,"

Comment: @VogonPoet The [2016 official UN report](https://www.unjiu.org/sites/www.unjiu.org/files/jiu_document_files/products/en/reports-notes/JIU%20Products/JIU_REP_2016_2%20_English.pdf) states that '*no United Nations system organization has a formal succession planning process in place*'.  Article 97 only describes the procedure for regular appointments. And the process can last for months. Please also note that questions about history are on-topic if '[asking for examples to construct a particular history for a world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)'.

Comment: @Otkin it's not universally true. In *all* questions there is a general expectation that a querent isn't lounging around treating participants like their personal research assistants. We expect a modicum of respect for each-other's time. I shared the specific language from help. To this "problem" 12 seconds gave me "should the secretary-general become unavailable, ...an under secretary-general is designated as officer in charge," Your own link states: "Should include... what information have you already looked at or failed to find?", This is simply and objectively discourteous and valueless.

Comment: This question asks about an existing organisation, its structure, and its policies. It is not very different from engineering questions that ask for currently existing solutions, except the former deals with organisational mechanics and the latter deals with mechanisms, machines, and alike. If engineering questions are not closed as off-topic questions about organisations should not be closed as well. Unless the community wants to declare questions about organisations off-topic. However, this would need a change in rules.

Comment: @VogonPoet Your comments are already not in compliance with the [code of conduct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/conduct). Please consider changing your tone. I would also want to attract your attention to the official SE FAQ: '[Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)'. Please also consider that the question is not as trivial as you attempt to present it. I just gave you the link to the official UN document stating that succession is a problem in the UN and all organisations in the UN system.

Comment: @Otkin - This question would be more suitable to the chat forum than engaging the entire community. There are readily available answers many can supply a link to.

Comment: @VogonPoet You are entitled to your opinions. But the OP is entitled to their choices as well. The WB.SE policies state that [the questioner's choices are to be respected](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate). You can voice your disagreement in a polite and respective manner. You can attempt to close the question. But you should follow the rules and code of conduct. Questions are not off-topic just because you are not happy with them.

Comment: @Otkin quite apart from the answer being trivially determined by a search engine query, there is a Politics SE for exactly this kind of question.  This question is roughly the equivalent of saying that a company of soliders need to fix the brakes on their model XYZ bicycles and asking what size hex key is needed on Worldbuilding SE instead of Bicycles SE.  For a real world question with a separate SE focused on that topic AND where the worldbuilding context is irrelevant, this is not the correct forum.

Comment: +1 every time I read that word *Jormungandr* I open Images.. this time I found  https://wallspic.com/image/164890-jormungandr_art-god_of_war-loki-art-concept_art

Comment: @Goodies, I did a Rhino3D model of Jormungandr... The only trouble was that it was so complicated that it would have taken ages to render... too many scales...

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 [Questions that can be answered on other stacks are not off-topic if the worldbuilding context is provided](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate).

Answer (score 7):

##### Someone Else

There is a line of succession. [This article](https://www.passblue.com/2020/03/23/in-a-crisis-does-the-un-have-a-leadership-succession-plan/) has some interesting history as well as an outline of how succession works. Not just when ASBs attack New York, but apparently when enough people are out to lunch or otherwise unavailable.

Presumably if enough top officials are killed, the Security Council would presumably decide on a replacement, which is [what happened in 1961](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweden_and_the_United_Nations) before they had a line of succession.

From the article, here is the [relevant UN Resolution](https://undocs.org/en/A/RES/52/12B) that establishes the Deputy Secretariat General.

Comment: As far as I know, the Deputy Secretary General is only abilitated to *act* in place of thr Secretary General in case of need; there is no rule that the Deputy Secretary General *succeeds* in the position of Secretary General in case the Secretary General falls prey to an errant bus or something. A new Secretary General still needs to be proposed by the Security Council and approved by the General Assembly.

Comment: @AlexP -- That's about as close as the UN gets to a formalised line of succession! We also have to realise that the UN is not a governing body of any kind. If the top two or three leaders died, no one would really notice outside of UN headquarters.